# Link to a div on another page

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have this code:

```
<div id="text"><p>Intertráfego is available to be reached at any time. Know
<a href="order_quotation.html#map">where we are</a> and <a
href="order_quotation.html#otherQuestion"> our contacts.</a></p></div>
```

The problem is that the link to the map doesn't work, the other works fine but, i tried also put a little invisible div on top of the map for the link and still doesn't work. Any tips?

Comment: does your `order_quotation.html` page have an element with a `map` name/id ?

Comment: yes it has http://www.iwanttobesanta.com/order_quotation.html on the bottom

Comment: and where did you put those links?

Comment: Opps just a sec. Wrong upload

Comment: ok it's done, on the index page

Comment: sorry, I can't see the link on the index (even I see them on the source code)

Comment: i uploaded now, sry for that. On index page, click the logo. Thanks